# Ruby group_by object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, grouping

I have an array or different objects and I want to group by objects. For example

```
 => [#<Graphic id: 3...">, #<Collection id: 1....">, #<Category id:...">, #<Volume id: 15...">] 
 all.size
 => 4
```

I tried

```
all.group_by(Object)
```

but that didn't work...any ideas on how to groupby objects in one array?

Comment: its in my question...i have 4 (Graphic, Collection, Category, Volume)

Comment: What property are you trying to group by?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you looking to do something like this?

```
all.group_by(&:class)
```

Which will group the objects in array by their class name

EDIT for comment

```
all.group_by(&:class).each do |key, group|
   group.each{|item| puts item}
end
```

Key is the grouping element and obj is the collection for the key, so this would loop through each group in the grouping and list the objects within that group

Also you could sort within the groupings pretty easily too

```
all.group_by(&:class).each do |key, group|
    group.sort_by(&:attribute).each{|item| puts item}
end
```

Comment: yes but that gives me an ordered hash ...how do i use that in the view. I want to display all the Collections first then all the Graphics and so on....so basically i want to use this array to group by the models and then loop through them but how do you loop through this ....
 => #<OrderedHash {Category(i

Comment: thanks Jimmy that is a great answer...do you know how to group them into 4 arrays all with the appropriate objects...so for example one array with @graphics and the next with @collections and so on...