# Combine Activerecord results in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I currently have a Order and image model which look like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Now i'd like to do the following:

```
<% @order.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image.format %> x  
  <%= image.amount %>
  <%= number_to_currency(image.price) %><br/>
<% end %>
```

This prints out this:

```
1x 30x30 € 1,00
1x 12x12 € 2,10
3x 30x30 € 3,00
4x 12x12 € 8,40
```

I'd like to combine this by image format, and sum the amount and price. But I've tried several methods but none seem to work because the @order.images isn't a simple array but an Image object. This is what I would like to achieve:

```
5x 12x12 € 10,50    
4x 30x30 € 4,00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`group_by`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768718/ruby-group-by-object):

```
@order.images.group_by(&:format).each do |format, images|
  <%= "#{images.length}x #{format} #{number_to_currency(images.sum(&:price))" %>
end
```

Should do the trick. `images` is an array of objects with equal values of `format`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [association extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images do
    def by_format
      select('sum(amount) as amount_sum, sum(price) as price_sum').group('format')
    end
  end
end
```

And then, in the view:

```
@order.images.by_format.each { |i| i.format,... i.amount_sum, ..., i.price_sum,... }
```

Comment: Didn't know that approach. Should work great, but I simplified my question a little bit, because the price field isn't a database field and therefore this wouldn't work. Interesting enough for the future though.